# how to handle http request error in blade?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am getting an HTTP request in my controller like this:

```php
try {
    $cards = $client = Http::acceptJson()->get('www.my.local', $request->input());
    $response = $client->json();

    if ($client->clientError()) {
        throw new HttpException(400, $error['errors'][0]['detail'] ?? 'Server busy');
    }

    return view('card::cards.index')
        ->with([
            'items' => $cards['data'],
            'meta' => $cards['meta'],
        ]);
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    return back()->withErrors($exception->getMessage())->withInput();
}
```

The error response:

```php
[ 
   "error" => "validate error",
   "fields" => [
      "id" => "init",
      ......
   ]
]
```

And somethings like this:

```php
[ 
    "error" => "server error"
]
```

I want to show all of the errors array in my blade but I can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can get errors in blade file and showing them using `$errors` variable which is available in your blade. [More info in laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

```
@if($errors->any())
    <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Comment: i see this error: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::__construct() must be of the type string or null, array given

Comment: Check if `$error['errors'][0]['detail']` is returning an array or not. You need to pass a string to `HttpException`

Comment: but i need to show all message like required fields